# AspnetBoilerpate REST Urls

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

After going through the documentation and also the github issues, I couldn't find a way to create RESTful apis. It only refers to use standard webapi implementation if we want to go RESTful.

Is there an alternative way(without completing re-writing current webapi implementation) to get the api's RESTful and at the same time get the serviceproxies to work with those?

Comment: you should read both [Create a Web API with ASP.NET Core and Visual Studio for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.0) and [angular HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http)

Comment: I figured out if I want to go RESTful the best way is to use .net core WebApis rather than relying on ABP dynamic webapis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create Restful API with Aspnet Boilerplate. Here's a sample to show you how to do it.

```cs
public class TestAppService : SwagResterAppServiceBase, ITestAppService
{
    [Route("api/services/app/Test")]
    [HttpPost]
    public Task CreateTest(TestDetailsDto input)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    [Route("api/services/app/Test")]
    [HttpDelete]
    public Task DeleteTest(EntityDto input)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    [Route("api/services/app/Test")]
    [HttpGet]
    public Task GetTest(EntityDto input)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    [Route("api/services/app/Test")]
    [HttpPut]
    public Task UpdateTest(TestDetailsDto input)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public interface ITestAppService: IApplicationService, ITransientDependency
{

    Task CreateTest(TestDetailsDto input);


    Task DeleteTest(EntityDto input);


    Task GetTest(EntityDto input);


    Task UpdateTest(TestDetailsDto input);
}

public class TestDetailsDto
{

}
```

Then run the `refresh.bat` to regenerate service proxies.

[image: Swagger Screen Shot Proof]

Comment: what is **SwagResterAppServiceBase**? i did a search in Object Browser as well to find a reference. but failed. I am using the latest ABP template with Angular. What am I missing here? Also does proxy generation works if we use Attribute routing with patterns? like [Route("customers/{customerId}/orders")]

Comment: it's a generated name for my project. your will be *AppServiceBase